# boost::asio::io_service run() returning despite work assigned?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Having read up on Boost.Asio tutorials and documentation, it seems to me that the following main() function should not return:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);

    boost::system::error_code ec;
    io_service.run(ec);

    std::cout << ec.value() << " - " << ec.message() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I've assigned it work and expect run() to block until the work is destroyed - which in this minimum viable demonstration doesn't happen until after run() returns.

However, the program returns immediately, displaying "0 - Success". That seems wrong.

I've encountered this after having tried a more complicated example using io_service.run() within a separate thread, and that also didn't work as expected. So a special case for detecting and avoiding deadlock situations seems unlikely.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? Is this a bug in Ubuntu's (14.04) Boost libraries? Any idea on how to debug or find out what the problem is?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior on my machine (VC11, Boost 1.55). You are right, the call to `run` should never return in your sample program as long as the `work` is kept alive. Can you try running the program under a debugger to see what is actually happening inside the call to `run`?

Comment: It seems this is indeed an issue with Ubuntu/GCC. Boost.Asio is a header-only library, so the choice of C++ compiler matters. Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) ships with GCC 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 by default, this is the one that breaks the above snippet for me on Boost 1.55.0.

Switching to clang++ solves the issue:

    sudo apt-get install clang;
    sudo update-alternatives --config c++;
    [select clang++];
    sudo update-alternatives --config cc;
    [select clang];

I'll file a bug in Launchpad. Thanks @ComicSansMS for verifying the correctness on a different platform.

Comment: I can't repro with any version of gcc on Ubuntu 13.10; also not with clang. I suspect UB (different compilation flags when building the Boost Library (libboost_system) vs. when building the program leading to ODR-violation)?